# Illegal string offset "name" Laravel 5.5 al enviar datos al formulario de edición

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy comenzando con Laravel 5.5.
Tengo un fallo de indefinición de variable cuando intento recuperar los datos para editar.
`Illegal string offset 'name' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-anuncios\resources\views\admin\edit.blade.php)`
Los datos cargan muy bien en la vista index y está tipado correctamente como String.

El error aparece al exportar los datos del usuario al Form de edición.

El var_dump() comentado en la función del controlador me confirma que recibe la variable name correctamente. Es un String con el nombre del usuario.

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        //
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        //var_dump($user['name']);
       return view('admin.edit', compact('user'));
    }
```

El formulario de la vista no es el problema porque el error me lo dispara con el formulario comentando. Aun asi lo copio.

```
    <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text center">Editor de Usuario</h1>

    {!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['AdminController@update', $user->id], 'files' => true]) !!}
        
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('id', 'Id') !!}
        {!! Form::number('id', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('id_rol', 'Rol') !!}
        {!! Form::number('id_rol', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('imagen', 'Imagen') !!}
        {!! Form::file('imagen', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('name', 'Nombre') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('email', 'Email') !!}
        {!! Form::email('email', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('password', 'Password') !!}
        {!! Form::password('password', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>


            {!! Form::submit('Editar', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) !!}

    {!! Form::close() !!}
   </div>
```

la ruta:

```
Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
```

Mi archivo index que carga los datos perfectamente:

```
  <div class="container-fluid"></div>
        <h1 class="text-center"> Usuarios</h1>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-dark">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Rol</th>
                        <th scope="col">Foto</th>
                        <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">Ultima actualizacion</th>
                        <th scope="col">Creado</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($users as $user)
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">{{$user->id}}</th>
                        <td>{{$user->id_rol}}</td>
                        <td><img src="images/{{$user->imagen}}" alt="imagen de usuario" width="150"></td>
                        <td><a href="{{route('admin.edit',$user->id)}}"> {{$user->name}}</a></td>
                        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->updated_at}}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->created_at}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

El error me salta en este lugar:

````
 * @param  string $value
     * @param  array  $options
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString
     */
    public function input($type, $name, $value = null, $options = [])
    {
        $this->type = $type;
 
        if (! isset($options['name'])) {
            $options['name'] = $name;
        }
 
        // We will get the appropriate value for the given field. We will look for the
        // value in the session for the value in the old input data then we'll look
        // in the model instance if one is set. Otherwise we will just use empty.
        $id = $this->getIdAttribute($name, $options);
 
        if (! in_array($type, $this->skipValueTypes)) {
            $value = $this->getValueAttribute($name, $value);
        }
 
        // Once we have the type, value, and ID we can merge them into the rest of the
        // attributes array so we can convert them into their HTML attribute format
        // when creating the HTML element. Then, we will return the entire input.
        $merge = compact('type', 'value', 'id'); ```

Gracias adelantadas.
````

Comment: ¿Y exactamente donde se genera el error?

Comment: @BetaM
En el momento que  intentamos editar a un usuario a través del enlace que existe en la celda nombre. ` <td><a href="{{route('admin.edit',$user->id)}}"> {{$user->name}}</a></td>` la función está en lo comentado.

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido solucionar el error pero no he descubierto su causa.

Comparto la solución por dos motivos:
1º Para si alguien dispone de un error parecido compruebe como lo he solucionado. Como se podrá comprobar de forma sencilla he usado un formulario html standard.

2º Para que algún lector con experiencia pueda indicar donde estaba el problema. Porque aunque sea bonito solucionar un problema aun más lo es conocer su causa.

Este es el formulario con el que funciona:

```
   <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.update',$user->id)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ $user->name }}" autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                    @error('name')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="id_rol" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Rol') }}</label>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="id_rol" type="number" class="form-control @error('id_rol') is-invalid @enderror" name="id_rol" value="{{ $user->id_rol }}" autocomplete="id_rol" autofocus>

                    @error('id_rol')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ $user->email }}" autocomplete="email">

                    @error('email')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <img class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right" src="../../../public/images/{{$user->imagen}}" alt="imagen de usuario" width="150">

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="imagen" type="file" class="form-control @error('imagen') is-invalid @enderror" name="imagen" value="{{ $user->imagen }}" autocomplete="imagen">

                    @error('imagen')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        {{ __('Guardar') }}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```